# IndexOutOfRangeException in my attempt to implement the FFT - fixed, edit: Output are only zeros, why?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# and I wanted to implement the following Pseudo code of the FFT algorithm:

```
function fft(n, f):
    if (n = 1)
        return f
    else
        g = fft(n/2, (f_0, f_2, ..., f_{n-2}))
        u = fft(n/2, (f_1, f_3, ..., f_{n-1}))
        for k = 0 to n/2 - 1
            c_k = g_k + u_k*exp(-2*pi*i*k/n)
            c_{k+n/2} = g_k-u_k*exp(-2*pi*i*k/n)
        return c
```

I tried to implement that in C# as you can see:

```
public static class FFT 
{
    public static Complex[] fft(Complex[] f)
    {
        if (f.Length == 1)
        {
            return f;
        }
        else
        {
            Complex[] g = fft(even_indices(f));
            Complex[] u = fft(odd_indices(f));

            Complex[] c = new Complex[f.Length];

            for (int k = 0; k < f.Length / 2 - 1; k++)
            {
                Complex w_k = u[k] * Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(1.0, -2 * Math.PI * k / f.Length);
                c[k] = g[k] + w_k;
                c[k + f.Length / 2] = g[k] - w_k;
            }
            return c;
        }
    }

    private static Complex[] even_indices(Complex[] f)
    {
        Complex[] f_even = new Complex[f.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                f_even[i / 2] = f[i];
            }
        }
        return f_even;
    }

    private static Complex[] odd_indices(Complex[] f)
    {
        Complex[] f_odd = new Complex[f.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                f_odd[(i-1)/2] = f[i];
            }
        }
        return f_odd;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Complex[] test = { 1.0, 2.454167, 8.4567, 9.4564 };
        var data = FFT.fft(test);
        Console.WriteLine("FFT");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now there is no error message and it gets completely compiled. However, the output is

FFT

(0, 0)

(0, 0)

(0, 0)

(0, 0)

which is not what I want. What is wrong here?

Thanks again

Comment: `c`,`g`, or `u` doesn't have k values. Set a breakpoint or look at the values when your error occurs.

Comment: Please see my update below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the error actually resulting from the next line:

```
c[k + f.Length / 2] = g[k] - u[k] * Complex.Exp(-w_k);
```

where you add len/2 to the k-index - which will eventually result in a index > length/2-1. (dev of 'c').

If the rest is correct you should declare c as:

```
Complex[] c = new Complex[f.Length];
```

Add:
in your code, the loop should iterate uo to len/2-1, so change to:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= f.Length / 2 - 1; k++)
```

Comment: I changed that. Now I am not getting the error message anymore from the Debugger but when the Console Window opens, it closes immediately. Actually I wanted that the Console shows me the result.

Comment: The console usually closes when the program finished. Set some Breakpoints (if using an IDE) and step through the program to see if everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`Complex[] c = new Complex[f.Length / 2 - 1];`

I would round up, so + 1..
`f.Length == 2` would return 0 for array length.

Comment: I changed it to f.Length/2 + 1, but I still get the error message.

Comment: Then I don't think you have to divide by two at all. No -1 or +1 either.
                c[k + f.Length / 2] = g[k] - u[k] * Complex.Exp(-w_k);
Needs these indices